# How to get templates to be matched in source XML order with XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this XML:

```
<document>
    <text>This is a text message with this ref:</text>
    <ref>ABC</ref>
    <text>, and this continues the message.</text>
</document>
```

And this XSL:

```
<xsl:template name="TOP" match="/document">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="text" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="ref" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text">     
    <xsl:element name="text">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ref">
    <xsl:element name="ref">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

How can I get the output to be more in the order of the source XML, like this:

```
<text>This is a text message  with this ref:</text>
<ref>ABC</ref>
<text>, and this continues the message.</text>
```

Currently it does this:

```
<text>This is a text message  with this ref:</text>
<text>, and this continues the message.</text>
<ref>ABC</ref>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear what your transformation is supposed to accomplish. If all you want is remove the root `document` element, you could do simply:

```
<xsl:template match="/document">
    <xsl:copy-of select="*" />
</xsl:template>
```

However, the result will be an XML fragment, not a well-formed XML document.

In any case, if you want to apply templates *and* keep the original order of `document`'s children, then do not apply templates to each one separately; instead of:

```
<xsl:template name="TOP" match="/document">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="text" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="ref" />
</xsl:template>
```

do:

```
<xsl:template name="TOP" match="/document">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="text|ref" />
</xsl:template>
```

or (assuming there are no other child elements you want to exclude):

```
<xsl:template name="TOP" match="/document">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```